# Removing the %sign from rows and converting them to number

Tags: r, type-conversion, gsub

I am trying to remove the % sign from my data and convert the same to numeric and then perform division on them. This is my data, it has part values in number and other in %.

[image]

I tried the following code to remove the % sign and then convert them to numbers. However, I want to perform division on the converted numbers only. Is there anyway wherein I can check and perform the division on only the rows which has % sign in them ?

This is my code

```
#Reading Files

tab1_data <-  read_excel("Dataset.xlsx", sheet = "tab1")
tab2_data <-  read_excel("Dataset.xlsx", sheet = "tab2")

#tab1_data$new <- subset(tab1_data$`Click percent`,grep("\\%$", tab1_data$`Click percent`))

d = as.numeric(gsub("\\%", "", tab1_data$`Click percent`))
```

This is the output of that converted column:
[image]

now, here the number 1.14000 should ideally come as 0.01146 but it doesn't.
I tried subsetting the % values in new column and then perform the division on them. however I am not able to subset them.

Can anyone pls provide any alternate way to achieve the end goal of removing the %sign and then performing division on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `x` is your column,

```
x <- c(0.02, 0.011, '1.14%', '1.309%')
```

then,

```
x[grepl('%', x)] <- as.numeric(gsub('%', '', x[grepl('%', x)])) / 100
x
#[1] "0.02"    "0.011"   "0.0114"  "0.01309"
```

or

```
as.numeric(x)
#[1] 0.02000 0.01100 0.01140 0.01309
```

Answer (score 1):

A fun option with `readr::parse_number(x)` using @Sotos' data

```
x <- c(0.02, 0.011, '1.14%', '1.309%')
readr::parse_number(x) / c(1, 100)[grepl("%", x) + 1] 
#[1] 0.0200 0.0110 0.0114 0.0131
```

This divides by 100 if `%` is present or with 1 otherwise.